# Filling in a ListView the correct way

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Hi I am trying to fill in a list view with 6 columns. I am filling them with this code:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();
ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem();
ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem();
ListViewItem item4 = new ListViewItem();
ListViewItem item5 = new ListViewItem();
ListViewItem item6 = new ListViewItem();


for (int i = 0; i < _leftTimeTable.Cars.Count; i++)
{

    List<TimeSpan> fgarList = _leftTimeTable.Cars[i].GetStopTimes(StopActions.FromGarage);
    List<TimeSpan> tgarList = _leftTimeTable.Cars[i].GetStopTimes(StopActions.ToGarage);

    _headersTable[i + 1, 0] = (i + 1).ToString();

    int column;

    item1.SubItems.Add(i.ToString());

    column = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < fgarList.Count && column < 4; j++)
    {                    
       item2.SubItems.Add(Car.GetFormattedTime(fgarList[j]));                    
    }

    column = _headersTable.GetLength(1) - 3;
    for (int j = tgarList.Count - 1; j >= 0 && column > 1; j--)
    {
        item5.SubItems.Add(Car.GetFormattedTime(tgarList[j]));                   
    }

    if (_leftTimeTable.Cars[i].GetDriverChangeTimes.Count > 0) _headersTable[i + 1, 5] = Car.GetFormattedTime(_leftTimeTable.Cars[i].GetDriverChangeTimes[0]);

}
listViewIzvlechenieLEFT.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6 });
```

So far so good but the data is filled the wrong way. It is not filled vertically it is filled horizontally. Is it possible to fill in the data vertically? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's a property called View which you use to set you view type

Comment: I think you mean to add a new `ListViewItem` for every element, not `SubItems`

Comment: I am setting the ListViewItem for every element. It is on the top of my code. It is set for each Item.

Comment: subitems are added horizontally and listviewitems are added vertically

Comment: item1 to item6 are declared as listviewitems but item1 doesn't have the "add" property it only has the SubItems.add :/

If I do this: item2.ListView.Items.Add(Car.GetFormattedTime(tgarList[j]));  the whole program crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every "row" in a ListView is represented by a single `ListViewItem`. Every column of that row is represented by the `SubItems` of the ListViewItem.

So if you want to fill a row with 6 columns, you do something like this:

```
ListViewItem itemX;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    itemX = new ListViewItem(i.ToString()); // First column
    itemX.SubItems.Add("Column 2")
    itemX.SubItems.Add("Column 3")
    itemX.SubItems.Add("Column 4")
    itemX.SubItems.Add("Column 5")
    itemX.SubItems.Add("Column 6")

    myListView.Items.Add(itemX); // Add the complete row to the ListView
}
```

The above example will add 10 rows to your ListView with 6 columns:

```
 1 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 2 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 3 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 4 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 5 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 6 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 7 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 8 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
 9 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
10 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6
```

Just make sure you created the columns in design mode and set the `View` property to `Details`.

Comment: Yep I saw my mistake earlier but I forgot to update. The problem was where I was adding the item1...item6 to the listview.